# jQuery get XML to list style

Tags: jquery

I have i XML file like this.

```
<products>
 <product>
  <name>Product title</name>
  <items>
   <item>AB123</item>
   <item>BC456</item>
   <item>CD6543</item>
  </items>
 </product>
 <product>
  <name>Product title</name>
  <items>
   <item>AB123</item>
   <item>BC456</item>
   <item>CD6543</item>
  </items>
 </product>
</products>
```

How can i easy, with jQuery transform it to list style on a page?

My file is called products.xml

```
<ul>
 <li>Product title
  <ul>
   <li>AB1234</li>
   <li>BC456</li>
   <li>CD6543</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Product title
  <ul>
   <li>AB1234</li>
   <li>BC456</li>
   <li>CD6543</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps

```
var products = $('<ul>');

$(xml).find('product').each(function () {
    var li = $('<li>'),
        self = $(this);
    li.text(self.find('name').text());

    var children = $('<ul>'),
        items = self.find('item');

    items.each(function () {
        children.append($('<li>').text($(this).text()));
    });
    li.append(children);
    products.append(li);
});

$('body').append(products);
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/MdEkg/